# PHP CHECKBOX Array Issue

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

I have a list of checkboxes like you would see in most email clients (You tick a box press delete then it deletes an email).

`<input type="checkbox" value="yes" name="box[]" />`

The problem stands here ...

`print_r($_POST['box']);//Returns nothing at all ...`

`var_dump($_POST['box']);// returns null...`

I was reading something about register globals that php5 has turned it off for security reason.

Does anyone know what my options are ?

Comment: Me being Captain Obvious: Have you explicitly set method="post" as a form attribute? The default method is get (try var_dump($_GET);)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found out by playing about with values.

Make sure you check for the **enctype** attribute on the  tag

should be `<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Hope someone else could find this helpful .